# Why $\int\sin\varphi\sqrt{r^2-2rz\cos\varphi+z^2}\,d\varphi$ results to having division by $rz$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

So I was trying to calculate this equation $\int \sin\varphi\sqrt{r^2-2rz\cos\varphi+z^2}\,d\varphi$, which I plug into calculator and get [the result](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=sin%28phi%29sqrt%28r%5E2-2rzcos%28phi%29%2Bz%5E2%29&intvar=phi&lbound=0&ubound=pi) as $\frac{(r^2-2rz\cos\varphi+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3rz}$. But having division by $rz$ seems wrong to me, cause for example let $z=0$, the original equation collapses into $\int (\sin\varphi) r\,d\varphi$, which is clearly integrate-able, while the original result will encounter division by 0.

And if looking from geometrical interpretation of that integral, it'll be the sum of distance from all points that are distance $r$ away from origin to the point located at $(0,0,z)$ (this coordinate is cartesian coordinate). So by setting $z=0, r>0$, it should equal to the volume of a sphere with radius=r.

And if you look at the graph of the function we're integrating:

[image: graph]

The area under that curve is definitely not infinity, so why the computer returns that result? And is that result correct? If so, then how could we calculate values where $z=0$ (cause the result doesn't converges to a value when $z$ approaches 0).

Comment: You took *an* antiderivative which is defined *up to a constant* (w.r.t. $\varphi$) whose behavior w.r.t. $z\to 0$ is the thing that confuses you. Try $\int_0^\phi$ instead.

Comment: @metamorphy but $\int_{0}^{\pi}$ means all the polar angle from 0 to $\pi$ in a sphere polar coordinate, how could I take $\int_{0}^{\varphi}\,d\varphi$? Did you take $\phi$ and $\varphi$ as two different variables? I did that in topic cause originally it reaches maximum length for topic, sorry if it's this reason.

Comment: Yes, *technically* these are different variables (but, after doing the integration, $\phi$ can be "renamed" to $\varphi$). Saying the same another way, let your antiderivative be $F(r,z,\varphi)$; the thing that confuses you is that it behaves badly as $z\to 0$. But $F(r,z,0)$ behaves just as badly, and $F(r,z,\varphi)-F(r,z,0)$ (which is *an antiderivative as well*) behaves "good".

Comment: This resembles $\int x^{a-1}\,dx=x^a/a$ which doesn't tend to $\int x^{-1}\,dx=\log x$ as $a\to 0$. But if we take $\int_1^x y^{a-1}\,dy=(x^a-1)/a$, things get in place.

Comment: @metamorphy in this occasion I'm doing definite integral from 0 to pi (because I'm working in sphere polar coordinate). But even doing definite integral the division by $rz$ doesn't disappears still (I suppose your F-F means definite integral?)

Comment: Yes, the division doesn't disappear, but the limit as $z\to 0$ becomes existing.

Comment: @metamorphy actually, let $F(r,z,\varphi)=\frac{(r^2-2rz\cos\varphi+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3rz}$, why would F(r,z,0) behaves badly? Won't it just equals to $\frac{|r-z|^3}{3rz}$?

Comment: Now take $z\to 0$. (And I suggest you to think first, not make a chat in comments.) Further "homework": compute $\lim\limits_{z\to 0}\big(F(r,z,\varphi)-F(r,z,0)\big)$ (assuming $r>z$ as we may for $z\to 0$). What do you see?